# How to get elements from text and set it on Map<String, boolean> on JAVA

Tags: java

I have a text file with pair `String`, `boolean` as follow:

```
Q1_R1       true
Q1_R2       false
Q1_R3       false
Q1_R4       true
Q1_R5       true
Q1_R6       true
Q1_R7       true
```

i want to fill a variable `Map<String, boolean>` with those elements figuring in the text automatically.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Yes. Parse the file, extract the elements, fill the map. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regex you can get the input every 2 pairs... which is the tupple 
***String, Boolean*** you need

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String input = "Q1_R1 true Q1_R2 false Q1_R3 false Q1_R4 true Q1_R5 true Q1_R6 true Q1_R7 true";
String[] pairs = input.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
Map<String, Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] kv = null;
for (String string : pairs) {
    kv = string.split(" ");
    myMap.put(kv[0], Boolean.valueOf(kv[1]));
}
System.out.println(myMap);
}
```

Comment: The question is asked to read the pair from a FILE, you are hard coding the inputs. Is answer from Norman more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a Scanner. For example:

```
    try {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("directory/yourFile.txt"))
      while(scanner.hasNext()) {
         yourMap.put(scanner.next(), scanner.nextBoolean());
      }
     } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```